# Mensagem Java Perspective

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: Java Perspective]

A mensagem esta sendo apresentada toda vez que eu executo o Eclipse e crio um novo Projeto, alguém sabe me explicar o motivo da mensagem?

Comment: Que tipo de projeto vc criou um java? jee?

Comment: Eu criei o meu projeto executando conforme segue: File -> New -> Java Project

Comment: Por exemplo estou trabalhando num projeto jee (com a mesma perspectiva) se eu criar um projeto novo do tipo java ele vai perguntar se desejo mudar a perspectiva. Outra sitauação onde isso ocorre é ao debugar algum código ele vai perguntar se quer mudar de perspectiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada tipo de projeto mostra determinada caracteristicas, sempre que criar ou mudar de projeto o eclipse perguntará se deseja mudar para perspectiva adequada ao projeto. Outra situação onde isso ocorre é ao debugar o projeto.

Para desativar essa pergunta faça o seguinte procedimento. Acesse o menu:

```
window>preference>general>perspectives
```

Na caixa que abrir marque a opção `never open`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]